# Enumeration of k-configurations by exact cover.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

I have been going over the book "Configuration of points and lines" by Branko Grunbaun. For 3-configuration he describes a recursive method to generate all combinatorial 3-configurations. There does not seem to be any general method recursive or otherwise for k-configurations k > 3.

I was wondering if the enumeration of all combinatorial k-configurations could be reform as an exact cover problem? Then one could use Knuth's Dancing Links (DLX) algorithm.  What I don't know is if you would still need to test if two difference configurations are the same (isomorphic).

Comment: Do you have a specific idea in mind for how to enumerate configurations by solving an exact cover problem?

Comment: I don't have any specific idea in mind. An orderly k-configurations table can be view as a k by n matrix where the first row is given (with 1 to n). Every other row has each n appears once and only once.  The numbers in any one column must be different, and two different column can't have two numbers in common.

But the exact cover has been used to solve sudoku problem.  I thought that a configurations table is some what like a sudoku problem. I had hope the the technique use for sudoku could be used for configurations.

Comment: *Solving* a sudoku problem is different from enumerating all possible sudoku problems.

Comment: Solving a sudoku problem by exact cover is not that difference. If there are more then one solution then the exact cover will give all solution.